# Create custom SELinux policy with full access

Tags: linux, security, redhat, selinux

I have a process `my_process` which should have access to all processes, files, ports, network traffic, etc. This process needs to work with SELinux.
How can I configure the appropriate policy?

I tried creating a policy using:

```
sudo sepolicy generate --init /opt/my_folder/my_process
semodule -i my_process_exec_t.pp
semanage fcontext -a -t my_process_exec_t "/opt/my_folder(/.*)?"
sudo restorecon -rv /opt/my_folder
```

But many avc errors appear in the `audit.log` file.

After that I tried using:

```
audit2allow -a -M my_process_exec_t
semodule -i my_process_exec_t.pp
```

But I still get a lot of errors in the audit.log file and some my_process features don't work. How can I configure the required policy?